Python auto-py-to exe issue
I'm trying to convert the following Python code into an executable file. I've experimented with various methods like auto-py-to-exe and py2exe, but I consistently encounter the same issue: the conversion process requires manual input.
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import os
import csv
from tqdm import tqdm
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor, as_completed
import sys

# Check if the script is being executed as an executable or in the development environment
if getattr(sys, 'frozen', False):
    # In executable mode (assign default values to avoid input during conversion)
    start_date = "240901"
    end_date = "240915"
    year = "2024"
else:
    # In development mode (ask for input in the console)
    start_date = input("Enter the start date (format: YYMMDD, e.g., 240901): ")
    end_date = input("Enter the end date (format: YYMMDD, e.g., 240915): ")
    year = input("Enter the year (format: YYYY, e.g., 2024): ")

# Generate the list of dates in the provided range
dates = []
for i in range(int(start_date[-2:]), int(end_date[-2:]) + 1):
    date = start_date[:-2] + str(i).zfill(2)  # Concatenate the year and day, ensuring it has two digits
    dates.append(date)

# Specify the directory and output file name
directory = os.path.join(os.getenv('USERPROFILE'), "Documents", "00_PJBC", "Data")
file_name = f"Data_{start_date}_{end_date}.csv"
file_path = os.path.join(directory, file_name)

# Create the directory if it doesn't exist
os.makedirs(directory, exist_ok=True)

# Function to process each URL
def process_url(date):
    url = f"https://www.pjbc.gob.mx/boletinj/{year}/my_html/bc{date}.htm"
    data = []
    
    try:
        # Request the webpage
        response = requests.get(url)
        response.encoding = response.apparent_encoding  # Use automatically detected encoding
        
        # Parse the HTML content
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
        
        # Find paragraphs and other elements that may contain the text
        paragraphs = soup.find_all(['p', 'div', 'span'], class_=['MsoNormal', None])
        
        # Extract relevant data
        for para in paragraphs:
            text = para.get_text(separator=" ").strip()  # Extract the text and clean spaces
            if text:
                data.append([text, date])  # Add the data to the list

    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error processing {url}: {e}")
    
    return data

# Number of threads (adjust based on available resources)
num_threads = 5

# Open the CSV file in write mode
with open(file_path, mode='w', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as csv_file:
    csv_writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
    
    # Write headers to the CSV file
    csv_writer.writerow(["Data", "Date"])  # Headers "Data" and "Date"

    # Create a progress bar
    with tqdm(total=len(dates), desc="Downloading pages", unit="page") as progress_bar:
        # Use ThreadPoolExecutor to handle downloads concurrently
        with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=num_threads) as executor:
            # Submit all URLs to the thread pool
            futures = {executor.submit(process_url, date): date for date in dates}
            
            # As tasks are completed, update the file and progress bar
            for future in as_completed(futures):
                result = future.result()
                if result:  # If valid data is returned
                    csv_writer.writerows(result)  # Write all downloaded data
                progress_bar.update(1)

print("Download complete, data saved to", file_path)


When using auto-py-to-exe with the 'one file' and 'Console Based' settings, the process stalls at '145067 INFO: Looking for dynamic libraries' and prompts me for input.
I'm seeking guidance on resolving this problem or understanding if I might be missing a crucial step, as I'm new to this process."

Hello, It looks like the script is actually looking for dynamic libraries some steps can take some time. are you sure there is an input, or the process is just a little bit long? Have you tried to just wait until it resolves ?

Thank you for your prompt response, @Lrx. I've rerun the conversion process, and it's still stalling at the 'INFO: Looking for dynamic libraries' stage. I've waited over 20 minutes, but there's no progress.

Ok, so auto-py-to-exe is a UI wrapper for another library named pyinstaller. It may be a version problem, some of them have been pointed out in past. Maybe you could fetch some more info on what's going on during the process by launching the build with the --debug (or -d) parameter and show us the last messages you've got.
